Sci-fi graphic novel/comic about a little boy with a robotic arm and face
I don't remember much about the story, but I remember how it started and what it looked like, just can't think of the name. I think it was a one-shot too, so it was a one-time comic book.
The little boy was looking through a dusty desert type of area and he had on a hooded cloak. He came across a robot that looked like it was dead but then it attacked the boy. The robot became a part of the boy by taking his arm (his right arm, I think) and a portion of his head/face. (Again, I think it was the right side.) The robotic arm was also bigger than the boy's regular arm, close to touching the ground.
The little boy wore the hooded cloak the entire time and I think you can see him wearing it on the cover. Also it's really likely that the title of the book is only one word long; I don't remember the title being long. Could have possibly also been in red text too. The cover was dark and dusty, matching the environment. Sorry, I don't remember anything about the story.

In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

I read the comic some years ago, maybe five years, and the book most likely came out in the late 2000s or early 2010s
